# Turn the first row into a column

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a spreadsheet organized by years which looks like this
DATA SET:

[image]

Now, I'm pretty sure that to make this data set 'tidy' i have to turn that Year row into a column. And have as a result the 3 columns, 1 with the model name, 1 with the year, and 1 with the units produced of that model in that year. I tried a few methods I know but couldn't solve it.

Can anyone suggest a method?

EDIT: I already substituted the NA with 0

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% gather(year, value, -1)`

Comment: Welcome. Please don't post images of your data - use ``dput()`` instead. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I will. Thank you very much for the help in the meantime! It worked perfectly